# Subquery or multiple queries in sql to get results

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have the following data sample below and I want get all the values for `c1` where there is a value of 0' in `c2` and 'Yes' in `c3`, but the only values I need returned are the rows where that condition is true but only need the one's where the subsequent values in `c3` are 'ADMIN'.

I've tried a subquery, but I don't think I really understand how those work because I keep getting an error. Not sure how to proceed or think through this. It seems to be needing a double query to the same table to get the results I want?

**Starting Data**

```
 c1 | c2 | c3
 ------------
 1 |  0 | Yes
 1 |  4 | Admin
 1 |  5 | Editor
 2 | 10 | Reader
 3 | -1 | Maybe
 3 |  9 | Admin
 3 | 13 | Editor
 3 | 12 | User
 4 |  0 | Yes
 4 |  8 | Admin
 4 |  2 | Admin
 5 | 11 | Editor
 5 | 16 | Admin
```

**Desired Result**

```
 c1 | c2 | c3
 ------------
 1 |  4 | Admin
 4 |  8 | Admin
 4 |  2 | Admin
```

Comment: show the query and what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN` to the subquery result:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t1 
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT c1
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  c2 = 0
   AND    c3 = 'Yes'
   ) t2 USING (c1)
WHERE  t1.c3 = 'Admin';
```

If there are many qualifying rows for `(c2, c3)`, an [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join should be faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  c3 = 'Admin'
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  c1 = t.c1
   AND    c2 = 0
   AND    c3 = 'Yes'
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code below.

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM table
WHERE c3 = 'Admin' AND c1 IN
 (SELECT c1, c2, c3
  FROM table
  WHERE c2 = 0 AND c3 = 'Yes')
```